# Не выходит передать результат запроса nodejs mysql2 в глобальную переменную

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

```
var url_id =[];

const mysql = require("mysql2");

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: USERNAME",
  database: "lab",
  password: "PASSWORD"
});

 const server = connection.connect((err)=>{
    if (err) {
      return console.error("Ошибка: " + err.message);
    }
    else{
      console.log("Подключение к серверу MySQL успешно установлено");
    }
 });

connection.query("SELECT id_prod FROM assortment",(err,res)=>{
  if(err) console.log(err);
  url_id = res;
  console.log(url_id[6]);
});

console.log(url_id);
```

Первый console.log() выводит правильный результат, а второй выводит просто пустой массив. Как это можно решить? Возможно я упускаю из виду что-то банальное. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Запрос `query` выполняется асинхронно, и в данном примере возвращается тот массив, который определен в первой строке - так и должно быть.
Освойте [Promise и асинхронные функции](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2#using-promise-wrapper), если не хотите мучаться с каллбэками.

Comment: var url_id =[];

const mysql = require("mysql2");

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: USERNAME,
  database: "lab",
  password: "PASSWORD"
});

 const server = connection.connect((err)=>{
    if (err) {
      return console.error("Ошибка: " + err.message);
    }
    else{
        server.query("SELECT id_prod FROM assortment",(err,res)=>{
        if(err) console.log(err);
        url_id = res;
        console.log(url_id[6]);
        });
    }
 });


console.log(url_id);